# Q promises propagate errors and exceptions

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, q

I am using this code in order to convert a classic nodejs function into a promise one:

```
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "toPromise", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(self) {
      var $this;
      $this = this;
      return function() {
        var arg, args, deferred, _i, _len;
        deferred = Q.defer();
        args = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = arguments.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
          arg = arguments[_i];
          args.push(arg);
        }
        args.push(function() {
          args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
          if (args[0] instanceof Error) {
            return deferred.reject.apply($this, args);
          } else {
            return deferred.resolve.apply($this, args);
          }
        });
        $this.apply(self, args);
        return deferred.promise;
      };
    }
  });
```

And I call it on a function to get another function. Like that:

```
  exports.list = (function(userid, options, callback) {
    // do something 
    // success ->
        callback(data);
    // error ->
        callback(err)
  }).toPromise(this);
```

**But when an exception that wasn't thrown by me (SyntaxError, TypeError...) is thrown, the `then` or `fail` function isn't called. How to propagate it automatically?**

I tried to replace toPromise by that but this didn't worked (even when it was working with my function)

```
  Object.defineProperty(Function.prototype, "toPromise", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function(self) {
      var $this;
      $this = this;
      return Q.denodeify(this.bind(Kitty));
    }
  });
```

I also tried applying a second callback to `then` but i didn't worked either.

Comment: WTH does `canThis` return a promise (you call `.then()` on it) but is placed in a function expression that you manually `toPromise()` then?

Comment: What is `error.throwError()`? Where is the error thrown that you can't catch?

Comment: If `canThis` does take a callback, did you then mean `, function(can)` instead of `).then(function(can)`?

Comment: @Bergi no I made a mistake : it is a promise

Comment: Then WTH are you doing with this `callback` thing and `.toPromise()`?

Comment: Btw, you just might use `args.push(deferred.makeNodeResolver());` instead of your own function expression.

Comment: @Bergi didn't worked too.... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when an exception that wasn't thrown by me (SyntaxError, TypeError...) is thrown, the then or fail function isn't called.

`Q` does only catch the exceptions that are thrown from a `.then()` callback. You need to deal with all other exceptions yourself explicitly.

> How to propagate it automatically?

If the exception is thrown from your own code, you might consider using Promises on a lower level, and put your own code in `then` callbacks only.

If the exception is thrown from "classic nodejs function" that you call, you will need to `catch` it. However, there might be good reasons why an exception is thrown (which is rather unrecoverable) in instead of just calling the callback with the error argument, which would be the "normal" design approach of an asynchronous node function.

If you would want to include such feature in your `toPromise` method, it would require to wrap the function call:

```
try {
  $this.apply(self, args);
} catch(e) {
  deferred.resolve(e);
}
```

---

> ```
> (function(…, callback) { … }).toPromise(this);
> ```

That's a bad idea. You should not use `toPromise` on your own functions, but only those that are given to you and have the non-promise interface. See [*The Beginning*](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/#the-beginning) in the Tutorial section how to come up with a function that returns a Promise genuinely. Do not use a `callback` variable. Too easily some error escapes you. Especially if you have a function that already yields a promise, all you need to do is chain other task after it.

In your specific case, it's simply

```
exports.list = function(userid, options) {
  return canThis(userid, "mod", "browse").then(function(can) {
    if (can === false)
      throw error.throwError("Forbidden", "UNAUTHORIZED");
    if (options.perPage > 50) {
      throw error.throwError("Too much mods per page", "INVALID_PARAMS");

    var Mod = mongoose.model("Mod");
    return Q.all([ // I would assume that listing and counting can happen in parallel?
      Q.ninvoke(Mod, "list", options),
      Q.ninvoke(Mod.count(), "exec")
    ]).spread(function(mods, count) {
      mods.totalCount = count;
      return mods;
    }, function(err) { // and throw this error when one happens in either?
      throw error.throwError(err, "DATABASE_ERROR");
      // not sure whether you need errors.handleResult at all
      // (not with a callback, at least)
    });
  });
};
```

Now all those `return`s actually make sense.

Comment: Thanks you very much. In a small test script I got the error printed w/o your code. However the output was different when adding you lines. I'll try in my app soon.

Comment: Why can't I use it on my own functions? it is simpler!

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't worked; When I run an undefined function, the page load and load and nothing happens, even though I add a console.log before resolve(e)

Comment: No, it's not simpler - and you want to use promises!

Comment: What do you mean by "*run an undefined function*"? A more specific code sample would be nice.

Comment: Calling foo() when foo is undefined. I should get TypeError

Comment: In the callback of another promise based function.

Comment: What callback? Where don't you get the error that you expect?

Comment: in exports.list I call another promise based function and in `then` if I make TypeErrors such as calling undefined function,, nothing happens.

Comment: Well, those errors will reject the promise, and if you don't handle promise rejections nothing will happen.

Comment: Maybe you did in the wrong place? It's hard to help without seeing the code. Some libraries provide a way to inspect unhandled rejections.

Comment: Which of these lines does throw? With that `callback` and `toPromise` approach you of course won't catch anything.

Comment: I didn't pushed anything b/c it doesn't work. however, I inserted `foo();` before line 24 - `foo` is undefined

Comment: Sure, the promise that is returned by the `then` *is rejected* by an error there. Yet you do not install any rejection handlers on it, and you even *cannot* do that because you use that `callback` thing. You will not notice anything in the promise that the `toPromise`d function returns.

Comment: Thanks! After the canThis I added a .fail and the exception was caught! Could you edit your answer?